# How to copy table contents from LibreOffice writer to plain text?

Tags: libreoffice, plaintext

If I select a table's contents and try to paste it into a plain text document, the layout gets severely broken.

```
+-----+----+
|one  |two |
+-----+----+
|three|four|
+-----+----+
```

becomes, regardless if I use Ctrl C/V or select/MMB,

```
one
two
three
four
```

Is it possible to get something like

```
one<tab>two
three<tab>four
```

or any other separator between cells except `<linebreak>`? The workaround with Calc can't be the only way...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool such as [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert LibreOffice ODT (and many other formats) to a plain text markup (e.g. Markdown, reStructuredText, AsciiDoc, MediaWiki, DokuWiki, Textile`).

A quick online test at [Try Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/) produced this:

**Markdown**

```
Test
====

  --------- -----
  Apples    100
  Oranges   77
  --------- -----

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**PHP Markdown Extra**

```
Test
====

|---------|-----|
| Apples  | 100 |
| Oranges | 77  |

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**ReStructuredText**

```
Test
====

+-----------+-------+
| Apples    | 100   |
+-----------+-------+
| Oranges   | 77    |
+-----------+-------+

--------------
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy task:

Menu `Table` -> `Convert` -> `Table to text...`. Now, you can select the separating character:

[image]

Comment: But I *don't* want to edit the source document...

Comment: You don't need to. Copy the table in a new LO Writer document, convert it as described and save as text (or copy&paste the output of the conversion).